# Unable to post http request to .Net Core 2.1 web project

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.1

Currently,I working on an Angular 6 and .Net Core 2.1 project. So, my Angular 6 code is in one project and .Net Core 2.1 controller methods for login authentication is in another project. To my observation both my projects are having different localhost port numbers. When I make Api calls from postman I can receive the results. But unable to post data from angular service to the controller method.

Now, I am having a scenario to post the login credentials to the controller method in my ValuesController. But whenever I am posting the credentials to controller method. I am getting **HttpErrorResponse**

Scenario 1:

When my Angular 6 code and controller(SampledataController) method are present in the same project, I could post the request and get the response successfully.

Scenario 2
But I am getting the issue when my Angular 6 code is in one project and .Net Core 2.1 controller methods for login authentication is in another project. 
That is from (WebProject)LoginService ----> (Api)ValuesController

[image]

LoginService.ts

```
AuthenticateUser(txtUsername: string, txtPassword: string) {

    this.userRoles.UserName = txtUsername;
    this.userRoles.Password = txtPassword;
    let parameters = new HttpParams().set('txtUsername', txtUsername)
                                     .set('txtPassword', txtPassword);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    const httpOptions = { headers: headers };
    return this._httpClient.post(this.base_url + "SampleData/AuthenticateUser/" + txtUsername + "/" + txtPassword , httpOptions);
}
```

ValuesController.cs

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

        [Route("[action]/{UserName}/{Password}")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> AuthenticateUser(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            return new string[] { UserName, Password };
        }
```

Below is my solution structure

```
Solution
    --> Angular project
         Components
               --login component
         Services
               --Login service
         Controller
               --SampleDataController

    --> WebApi Project
         --Controller
              -- ValuesController
```

Could you please help me resolving the issue as I am entirely new to this.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information I have I would check have you CORS enabled? (It sounds like this is the problem because postman does not do a preflight request but your browser does. Along with this you are probably not managing your Server responses correctly and this is why you are getting a funky 404. possibly because your API is trying to redirect to a login page that does not exist.

to enable CORS for all domains add `app.UseCors();` in the Configure method of Startup

the documentation for enabling CORS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I am able to log the server response and debug when my webApi methods & Angular service calls are present in same project. But when api methods and services are in different projects unable to even debug either.

Comment: Which is why I think you may not have CORS enabled. If the API and angular project have same origin when in the same project no pre-flight request is sent by the browser since they are not cross origin. Once you split them into different projects and they have have different origins your requests will fail from browsers unless you enable CORS on your API

Comment: enabled cors using `app.UserCors()` but still facing the issue.

Comment: you really need to fix your error handling and server responses so you can Identify the actual problem 404 not found is no help when trying to debug an error. Have you logging in your API? ...without CORS being enabled your requests would most certainly fail  if your API and Angular app are on different ports.